# Pandas forward fill ffill() until the condition of another column is false

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that consists of three columns. The last column is the 'value' which I want it to return 't' once the 'on' indicator is 1 until the 'off' indictor is switched on.

`d1={'on?':[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],'off?':[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],'value':[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]} df=pd.DataFrame(d1)`

The below is my desired output. I tried using the `df['value']=np.where(df['on?']==1,1,0)` but apparently it applies to the whole column and would not stop filling as it matches the 'off?'.

Can someone guide me through what is the best function to do a forward filling function until a certain condition is met/not met?

[[image: Desired Output1]

Answer (score 4):

```py
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
   on?  off?
0    0     0
1    1     0
2    0     0
3    0     1
4    0     0
5    1     0
6    0     0
7    0     0
8    0     0

In [28]: df['value'] = (df['on?'] - df['off?']).cumsum()

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   on?  off?  value
0    0     0      0
1    1     0      1
2    0     0      1
3    0     1      0
4    0     0      0
5    1     0      1
6    0     0      1
7    0     0      1
8    0     0      1
```

it might be easier to understand it if you think about it as

1. `a = df['on?'].cumsum()` which gives you a cumulative sum of ons
2. `b = df['off?'].cumsum()` which gives you a cumulative sum of offs
3. what you then require is `a - b` i.e. `df['on?'].cumsum() - df['off?'].cumsum()` which can be simplified into `(df['on?'] - df['off?']).cumsum()`

---

EDIT: Based on the comment -

> One problem with the above solution is that IF a value of 1 first appears in the Off? column, then the value will then starts with -1 and will only change between 0 and -1. How to solve that / set a minimum / a condition that do not count any off? until on? indicator is on?

```py
In [161]: df['on_count'] = df['on?'].cumsum()

In [162]: df
Out[162]:
   on?  off?  on_count
0    0     1         0
1    1     0         1
2    0     0         1
3    0     1         1
4    0     1         1
5    1     0         2
6    0     0         2
7    0     0         2
8    0     0         2
```

you could group by the "on_count" - which is the cumsum of the on column; and then apply the same logic

```py
In [170]: grouped_cumsum = df.groupby('on_count')[['on?', 'off?']].cumsum()

In [171]: grouped_cumsum
Out[171]:
   on?  off?
0    0     1
1    1     0
2    1     0
3    1     1
4    1     2
5    1     0
6    1     0
7    1     0
8    1     0

In [174]: df['value'] = (grouped_cumsum['on?'] - grouped_cumsum['off?'])

In [175]: df.loc[df['value'] < 0, 'value'] = 0 # or however else you wan't to deal with

In [177]: df.drop(columns='on_count')
Out[177]:
   on?  off?  value
0    0     1      0
1    1     0      1
2    0     0      1
3    0     1      0
4    0     1      0
5    1     0      1
6    0     0      1
7    0     0      1
8    0     0      1
```

Comment: This works given it happens the first two columns are either 1 or 0. However, if they are in True and False (boolean or even string), what would be your opinion to solve this given now you can't use operator / cumsum to replicate it? Is there any other logic operator that can acheive it?

Comment: booleans can be used directly since they're just 1/0 behind the scenes. how would a string column look like? as long as there's 2 categories in that column, you can convert it into a 0/1 column

Comment: One problem with the above solution is that IF a value of 1 first appears in the Off? column, then the value will then starts with -1 and will only change between 0 and -1. How to solve that / set a minimum / a condition that do not count any off? until on? indicator is on?

Comment: I don't understand what does `grouped_cumsum = df.groupby('on_count')[['on?', 'off?']].cumsum()` actually try to do and the concept behind?

Comment: maybe a chat is better? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233519/67883674